# Parallelization in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

We are using Azure Databricks cluster (E64s_v3 (432GB RAM, 64 Cores); Worker's = 12) to run the scala code. We are trying to parallelize the writing of data by worker node so we can have all the cores working for it. Using "*new scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool(8)*" to parallelize the writing of data. We have 2B of records and all of them can be segregated by 50 Ids, our goal is to have 1 worker working on each Id of data with all the cores running so we can have 12 paralleling writings happening with all the cores working. Below is the piece of code that we have used

`sTpids.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport( new scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool(8)  ) sTpids.foreach(p => {   trnMap.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(partitionPath) }`

From our observation, the processes is not parallelizing instead all the workers are working on writing 1 Id at a given time and only 1 core per worker is being used. Can you some one help me understand why this is happening ?

Comment: I might be missing something but why not use pure Spark? Instantiating a pool of threads within Spark look's like an anti pattern

Comment: @GaëlJ  how would you manage task allocation to executor in Spark? The task above applies custom allocation logic that requires keeping entire segment information in one executor (i.e. there is `groupByKey` followed by collect). As @Chaitanya mentioned, there are 50 segments, but only 8-12 executors. I didn't find any other option how to make Spark to take only ~8 groups at once.

Comment: could you partition it so each id has its own partition and use `mapPartitions` to treat each partition as an Iterator. Each core works on one id, all cores engaged, all recs for a given id are now treated as if in an iterator.